# Mail is appearing on old server on occasion despite being set up 5 months ago

Tags: email, email-server

I moved a domain 5 months ago, and do not have access to the old mail server.

A and MX records are all pointing to the new server.

Most of the mail has started coming to the new accounts, however they occasionally go to the old accounts still. 
When it goes to the old account, looking at the headers of the mail, it includes the old server's information.

The client is too scared to drop their old server since mail is still going to it. Why is this happening? How would one go about solving it?

old mail server: xserver

new mail server: sakura

Comment: Ask mail admins of those occasional messages' senders. There may be static mail routing instead of dynamic MX-based.

Comment: @Vadim It even goes to the old accounts when sent within the same domain on occasion apparently, so it isn't just some specific senders.

Comment: Maybe some of your clients are using the _old_ server to _send_ mail? If that's the case, the mails won't go out as the accounts are seen as local.

Comment: @MrShunz It works correctly most of the time for each of the clients, but on occasion mails sent to them will go to their old account. They can send mails just fine -- though sometimes mails sent within the domain will not be delivered at all apparently.

Comment: Does "sent within the same domain" means the user connecting to new mail server while sending?

Comment: @Vadim  It means sending a mail to someone in the same company from the new mail server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xserver handles all requests within xserver before looking up a domain, so any mail sent from an xserver mail server would arrive at the old account. The issue with people within the same company not arriving is they were sending it from the old account (despite insisting they sent the mail from their new account) which caused it to arrive at xserver.

I have convinced the client to drop the xserver mail server.

Comment: As an update, this fixed all the issues.